# Configure on-demand VPN feature comparable to the iOS on-demand VPN

Tags: vpn, android-enterprise

I have an Android device running one or more apps that need a VPN connection to reach a backend within our corporate network. On iOS devices, there is an on-demand VPN feature where, when the user opens the app, iOS automatically triggers the VPN connection (in the background, without user inaction). We are able to configure this behaviour from our MDM provider portal.

It seems as though the Android platform itself supports this as some MDM platforms have documentation showing how to enable this feature ([source](https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/KB44365?language=en_US)). Our MDM provider, however, doesn't. Have put in a feature enhancement request. In the interim, however, is there a way we can configure this behaviour on the device itself?